# Is it "faster and safest" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I've just read the following sentence and it looks wrong to me, is it correct?

*We are creating a brand new operative system, faster and safest than any other we have used.*

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Questions that do not show prior research are considered [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What's an "operative system"? It sounds like a system that works as opposed to one that doesn't (an "inoperative system"). So as long as my brakes are sufficient to stop my car, I can consider them to be an operative system. (If the intention was to describe the software that is first loaded onto a computer in order to allow any other software to be used, that's an _operating system._)

Comment: @DavidK We are in need of more context here...

Comment: @SovereignSun Yes, we do need more context. The word "safest" is clearly wrong (unless we rewrite the sentence as in your answer), but other words are used in combinations that seem unusual. "Creating" and "used" also strike me as possibly incongruous. It seems appropriate to raise questions about these other words. (After all, the full question literally asks whether the _sentence_ is correct.) Context might resolve these other concerns or it might confirm that they are indeed errors.

Comment: @DavidK I agree; until then my answer is firm. I state it to be an incorrect sentence.

Comment: @SovereignSun I completely agree that your answer is correct. I find it hard to imagine what context could make the word _safest_ grammatical where it occurred in the question. I have doubts only about some of the other words in the sentence.

Comment: You are all right, the sentence is awfull, as the "operative system" they are trying to sell (they claim to be the spanish Microsoft), I wanted to be sure anyway. About the prior research, I'm used to reading english but not to writing so I had no clues on where should I search, thanks and I'll take the site tour.

Comment: @JotaGe Mark the question as answered if there is nothing more to be discussed here.By the way, it should be "clues on where I should search".

Comment: @SovereignSun Oh right, it's done! I see that I should have asked on English Language Learners anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it as a grammatically incorrect construction.

(http://www.thefreedictionary.com/safest) - You can't use "safest" in such a way.

**"We are creating a brand new operative system, faster and safer than any other we have used."** - **"that is faster and that is safer than"**

or it should be: **"We are creating a brand new operative system that is faster than, and the safest among any other we have used."**

Comment: Read about COMPARATIVE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative) and SUPERLATIVE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superlative)